# How to find a rectangular matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

Let

```
    A={{729, -243, 243, 243, 243, 243}, {-243, 729, 243, 243, 243, 
  243}, {243, 243, 729, -243, 243, 243}, {243, 243, -243, 729, 243, 
  243}, {243, 243, 243, 243, 729, -243}, {243, 243, 243, 243, -243, 
  729}}
```

Could anyone please help me use Mathematica to find a $6\times 4$ matrix B, such that $BB^{T}=A$? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the singular value decomposition to do this. Writing `{u,w,v} = SingularValueDecomposition[A]` gives you the decomposition of $UWV^T = A$. Furthermore, because $A$ is symmetric $U=V$. Now notice that $W$ is diagonal with the last two entries $0$. This lets us write $B=U_{1:4}\sqrt{W_{1:4,1:4}}$, where $U_{1:4}$ is the first 4 columns of the $U$ matrix, $W_{1:4,1:4}$ is upper-left $4\times 4$ submatrix of $W$, and the square root is applied entry-wise.

Comment: In fact, precisely because $A$ is symmetric, one can just use `Eigensystem[]` instead: `{vals, vecs} = MapAt[Orthogonalize, Eigensystem[A], {2}]; With[{pos = Position[vals, x_ /; x != 0]}, B = Transpose[Extract[vecs, pos]].DiagonalMatrix[Sqrt[Extract[vals, pos]]]];`

Comment: dskeletov, thank you very much for your answer on the method.